# How do i declare a static generator method in ES6 class

Tags: ecmascript-6, generator, es6-class

How do i declare a static generator method in ES6 class ?

```
class Person
{
  static *getData(){
  }
}
```

Build when no export of the class is specified

[image: No EXPORT SPECIFIED]

[image: WITH EXPORT]

Comment: Did you try it? Your example code doesn't throw a syntax error, which I feel is pretty clear.

Comment: works when we dont export the class ,updated post with screenshots

Comment: Error message on your screenshot clearly says what's wrong. It's about flow types. This has nothing to do with generators, or export, or ES6 in general.

Comment: When you export values from a module then flow expects them to be annotated.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a problem with flow type.

```
static* getData<T>(): Iterable<T> {}
```

Try with this form.